# How can I load CoffeeScript files from bower packages with webpack?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, bower, webpack

I am in the process of splitting up an Angular application, so the service layer can be re-used. I know it's possible to preprocess coffee files in webpack modules, but what about bower packages? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the coffee loader - https://github.com/webpack/coffee-loader and provide the path:

```
require("coffee!./bower_components/strawberry_module/src/tasty.coffee")
```